# Lemma 3.3-7 and Theorem 3.6-2 in Kreyszig's "Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications": What if completeness is lost?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $X$ be an inner product space, and let $M$ be a non-empty subset of $X$. Then we have the following:

(a) If the space of $M$ is dense in $X$, then $M^\perp = \{0 \}$, that is, $x \in X$, $x \perp M$ imply $x =0$.

(b) If $X$ is complete and $M^\perp = \{0 \}$, then the span of $M$ is dense in $X$.

In (b), what if the space $X$ is not complete? In such a case, can we have a set $M$ such that $M^\perp = \{0\}$, but the span of $M$ is not dense in $X$?