# Theorem 3.6-2 in Erwine Kreyszig's "Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications:" Does the converse hold if the space is not complete?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

First, a definition:

Let $X$ be a normed space. A subset $M (\neq \emptyset) \subset X$ is said to be total in $X$ if the span of $M$ is dense in $X$.

Now theorem 3.6-2 in Kreyszig states the following:

> (a) If a subset $M \neq \emptyset$ of an inner product space $X$ is dense in $X$, then $M^\perp = \{ 0 \}$.
>
> (b) If $X$ is a Hilbert space and if $M$ ( $\neq \emptyset$ ) $ \subset X$ such that  $M^\perp = \{0\}$, then $M$ is total in $X$.

So far, so good!

Now my question is, what if $M^\perp = \{0\}$, but $X$ is not a complete inner product space? Can we find a non-trivial  example of such a set $M$ which is not total in $X$?

Comment: Isn't this answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286198/lemma-3-3-7-and-theorem-3-6-2-in-kreyszigs-introductory-functional-analysis-wi)?